# Python Instagram login using requests

Tags: python-requests, python-3.7, instagram-api

I am trying to login to Instagram with python. I am able to get the csrf Token but the `requests.Session().post()` doesn't seem to post the login data to the website correctly. I always get the `class="no-js not-logged-in client-root"`. I've been searching for a while and also tried to login into some random sites which seemed to work. In the login method I just start a `requests.Session()` and make a post request to the https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ with the login name and password as the `data` parameter.

```
def login(self):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        p = s.post(self.loginUrl, data=self.loginData, allow_redirects=True)
```

Also please don't tell me to use Selenium I strictly want to do it with requests.

Answer (score 3):

Currently (January 2021) a working solution to log into Instagram using Python is the following:

```
def login(username, password):
    """Login to Instagram"""

    time = str(int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()))
    enc_password = f"#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:{password}"

    session = requests.Session()
    # set a cookie that signals Instagram the "Accept cookie" banner was closed
    session.cookies.set("ig_cb", "2")
    session.headers.update({'user-agent': self.user_agent})
    session.headers.update({'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com'})
    res = session.get('https://www.instagram.com')

    csrftoken = None

    for key in res.cookies.keys():
        if key == 'csrftoken':
            csrftoken = session.cookies['csrftoken']

    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken})
    login_data = {'username': username, 'enc_password': enc_password}

    login = session.post('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/', data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})

    cookies = login.cookies
    print(login.text)

    session.close()
```

Comment: Tried this - does not seem to work anymore, {"message":"checkpoint_required","checkpoint_url":"blablabla","lock":false,"flow_render_type":0,"status":"fail"}. They're quick at fixing stuff like that !

Comment: This works great for me...atleast on my local machine, but on my server there is this error...`raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"`

Comment: If you want to log out just do `session.post('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/logout/ajax/')`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code:

```python
import requests

#Creating URL, usr/pass and user agent variables

BASE_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
LOGIN_URL = BASE_URL + 'accounts/login/ajax/'
USERNAME = '****'
PASSWD = '*******'
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
 Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'

#Setting some headers and refers
session = requests.Session()
session.headers = {'user-agent': USER_AGENT}
session.headers.update({'Referer': BASE_URL})


try:
    #Requesting the base url. Grabbing and inserting the csrftoken

    req = session.get(BASE_URL)
    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': req.cookies['csrftoken']})
    login_data = {'username': USERNAME, 'password': PASSWD}

    #Finally login in
    login = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})

    cookies = login.cookies

    #Print the html results after I've logged in
    print(login.text)

#In case of refused connection
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print("Connection refused")
```

I found it in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJbKulrw7Ak) Youtube video. It worked for me, I hope it can work for you too.

Comment: no this method doesn't work. I messed around with it and I get a ```KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"``` Error.

Comment: In what part of the code are you getting that error? Just in case my requests module version is **2.22.0**

Comment: I first tried to edit my code to somewhat equal the code you gave me. After I got the csrftoken error I tried configuring my previous that already has the csrf Token but I still got the ```class="no-js not-logged-in client-root"```

Comment: You have to add a cookie ig_cb=2 in the request lately, see my answer.