# Python Request - Login to Instagram

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram-api

Since I found out about requests I tried to log in to Instagram.
I found this interesting article about it:

[Python Instagram login using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58520305/python-instagram-login-using-requests/65892587#65892587)

But after trying it didn't work. An error occurred saying:
Traceback (most recent call last):

- line 41, in 
  test.login("MyInstagramName", "MyInstagramPassword")
- line 32, in login
  session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})
- line 328, in **getitem**
  return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
- line 399, in _find_no_duplicates
  raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
  KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"

[image: The code i used]

Looks like there is a problem with "self._find_no_duplicates(name)" which triggers the  "KeyError('name=%r, do...".

Is it because of the csrf-token?

```
import requests
import datetime


class instagram:
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36'

    def login(self, username, password):
        """Login to Instagram"""

        time = str(int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()))
        enc_password = f"#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:{password}"

        session = requests.Session()
        # set a cookie that signals Instagram the "Accept cookie" banner was closed
        session.cookies.set("ig_cb", "2")
        session.headers.update({'user-agent': self.user_agent})
        session.headers.update({'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com'})
        res = session.get('https://www.instagram.com')

        csrftoken = None

        for key in res.cookies.keys():
            if key == 'csrftoken':
                csrftoken = session.cookies['csrftoken']

        session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken})
        login_data = {'username': username, 'enc_password': enc_password}

        login = session.post('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/', data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
        session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})

        cookies = login.cookies
        print(login.text)

        session.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = instagram()
    test.login("InstaUsername", "InstaPassword")
```

Comment: Try use a different user agent, the server might not like your current one. You can copy and paste a user agent from [this](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/chrome/) website.

Comment: @Jared Hi I tried some of them but nothing changes I guess something is wrong with the csrftoken...