# how to get json file from Instagram URL?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, request

i want to download photos from instagram using python.

Previously I used this method to get the json data

```
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/Ch656GRoyuO/?__a=1'
SESSIONID = '9hfMsiKKe8YHWVqVYG9xv3h8f7MITWWZ'
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edg/87.0.664.57",
            "cookie": f"sessionid={SESSIONID};"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()["items"]
```

but when the url should be added `&__d=dis` returns error `raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos) requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

how to get json data using python from this url?
`https://www.instagram.com/p/Ch656GRoyuO/?__a=1&__d=dis`

Comment: You won't be able to access this data without being logged in. If u can't auth yourself in the https request you will only receive the html file to login.

Comment: I recommend using selenium, as you can then login, And get the actual data you want :)

Comment: @Oivalf  I have tried to log in like the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462398/python-request-login-to-instagram) but still getting the same error :(

Comment: As @Thornily said, using selenium is an easy way to log in. Try to use that if it's not working the manually way.

Answer (score 0):

i will try to solve this issue for you...

BEFORE
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/Ch656GRoyuO/?__a=1'

CHANGE THIS TO ONE
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/Ch656GRoyuO/media?id='

tell me whether it's works or not ..okey

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).